# unique identifier for each name and surname in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have table like below with first and last name:

| person1 | person2 |
| --- | --- |
| Helene Fischer | Jennifer Lopez |
| Beyonce | Jennifer Lopez |
| Jennifer Lopez | Beyonce |

as query result, I want to get unique ID for each name and surname like below:

| person1 | person2 | uniqueId1 | uniqueId2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Helene Fischer | Jennifer Lopez | A123 | A124 |
| Beyonce | Jennifer Lopez | A125 | A124 |
| Jennifer Lopez | Beyonce | A124 | A125 |

how I can prepare my "select" script for result table? thanks in advance

Comment: Presumably you don't already have a table with all the unique people in it, possibly even with an ID you can use; but can you create one? What format or logic rules do you have to define the ID? And if you're just generating it in the result set, are you expecting the ID for each person to remain the same across multiple executions, even if people are added or removed; or is it completely transitory (which makes it seem a bit pointless)?

Comment: Actually, my aim is to generate a guid or unique Id for the name and surname combination, which is sensetive information in two different columns, there are no rules for generating ID here.

Comment: So you could hash the names, which would stay the same but has a risk of collisions (how much of a risk depends on the hash method); or pull all the unique values from both columns into a CTE and use `row_number()` to give each one a numeric ID or sys_guid() for a GUID... it depends what you want to see, and to some extent how much data you have and how performant various approaches are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to approach this. One is to hash the names, e.g.:

```
select person1, person2,
  standard_hash(person1, 'MD5') as unique_id1,
  standard_hash(person2, 'MD5') as unique_id2
from your_table;
```

| PERSON1 | PERSON2 | UNIQUE_ID1 | UNIQUE_ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Helene Fischer | Jennifer Lopez | 0x98E66FAC0FD3E55EC79F7538842067E6 | 0xE41C2D43B624E9237CE154512F47DE53 |
| Beyonce | Jennifer Lopez | 0x3AE5DABEA04CBA4CE60FA41DFAF36EEC | 0xE41C2D43B624E9237CE154512F47DE53 |
| Jennifer Lopez | Beyonce | 0xE41C2D43B624E9237CE154512F47DE53 | 0x3AE5DABEA04CBA4CE60FA41DFAF36EEC |

Or you could get all the unique names and assign a rank or GUID to each one:

```
select person, row_number() over (order by person), sys_guid()
from (
  select person1 as person
  from your_table
  union
  select person2
  from your_table
);
```

and then use that as an inline view or CTE to join to:

```
with ids (person, id) as (
  select person, row_number() over (order by person)
  from (
    select person1 as person
    from your_table
    union
    select person2
    from your_table
  )
)
select person1, person2,
  ids1.id as unique_id1,
  ids2.id as unique_id2
from your_table
join ids ids1 on ids1.person = person1
join ids ids2 on ids2.person = person2;
```

| PERSON1 | PERSON2 | UNIQUE_ID1 | UNIQUE_ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Helene Fischer | Jennifer Lopez | 2 | 3 |
| Beyonce | Jennifer Lopez | 1 | 3 |
| Jennifer Lopez | Beyonce | 3 | 1 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cf061c8361ff4f40ad8439ca5ec572ae) with those and some minor variations.

A better long-term prospect would be to have a separate table with the unique names and an ID, and make the values in this table have a foreign key relationship to enforce data integrity.